# Approximation for Euler number using do loop (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to calculate and approximation for the Euler number using a do loop in Scheme

Something is not quite right because nothing is displayed. Can someone help me to find the fix for the code below? Thanks.

```
(define (factorial n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0)1)
    ((* n(factorial(- n 1)))))) 

; using a do loop, I want to calculate 1/0! + 1/1! + 2/2! + 3/3!...
(define (ei n)
  (define sum 0)

  (do ((i 0 (+ 1 i)))
     ((> i n)) 
     (+ sum (/ 1.(factorial i)))))



(ei 6)
```

I expect a number close to 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the sum variable and also return its value:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 1)
    ((* n (factorial (- n 1)))))) 

(define (ei n)
  (define sum 0)

  (do ((i 0 (+ 1 i)))
     ((> i n))
     (set! sum (+ sum (/ 1. (factorial i)))))

  sum)

(ei 6)
```

This results in `2.7180555555555554`.

Comment: Bravo! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that a `do` loop can update multiple variables.

```
(define (factorial n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 1)
    ((* n (factorial (- n 1)))))) 

(define (ei n)
  (do ((i   0   (+ 1 i))
       (sum 0.0 (+ sum (/ 1. (factorial i)))))
      ((> i n) sum)))
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. I like it.